# Automatically build some project when Visual studio loses focus

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a editor extension asset for unity. The project has some codes that are unity-dependent and some algorithm codes that are unity-independent. I moved the non-unity code to a separate class library project in the same solution and I have set the output to unity project's asset folder. It works fine and when I make changes to the source of DLL, the DLL gets updated after building in VS and Unity realizes the changes and recompiles. Everything is Ok except that I have to build the DLL project everytime I make changes and it is very easy to forget that or build the unity project instead of DLL project.

So I am asking how can I tell VS to:

1. Build the DLL project every time I save one of its files
2. **Or better**, build the DLL project every time visual studio loses focus (because probably I switched to unity or some other program)

Comment: Triggering a build every time Visual Studio loses focus could cause a lot of problems. Also, are you aware that you can configure project dependency information in Visual Studio that will trigger a build of dependencies when you initiate a build of the dependent project as long as they are in the same solution? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3.aspx.

Comment: I dont think that VS has a build in way to do that. But you can do that by listening to lost focus event of VS and then build the project with MSBuild or Roslyn. You also can do it when text has changed.

Comment: @JamieSee i agree with the point. This is due to unity's build workflow and this is the standard way to make DLLs in unity.

Comment: @DudiKeleti I hoped I don't have to go that way but you are right and I have to make an extension to do that.